# Rails+Devise: How to make some actions available only for users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, admin

Because the application I am working on will not have many administrators, I've added to the `user` model a column **admin** for recognising if the respective user is admin or not.

In the controller, I would need to use ** before_filter :authenticate_admin!** filter, but this one is available only if in the application is model `admin`.

How to add this filter if I use only the column attribute for admin, not the whole model?
Testing

```
if current_user.try(:admin?)
  # do something
end
```

in each action is not very practical.

Is there an inner filter for the variant when is used a column for the admin account?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom filter

application_controller

```
def authorize_admin
  if !current_user.admin?
    redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Not Allowed") and return
  end
end
```

And use in your controller

```
before_filter :authenticate_user
before_filter :authorize_admin, :only => [:create]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the actions which only admin can use, you can set a before filer to be executed. Say
you want the access to be available for the below method only to admin

```
def create_new_users
  User.create(name: "xxxx", email: "first@mail.com")
end
```

use the below code in application_controller which checks for access for the method available only for admin. so use

```
before_filter :authenticate_user_access, :only => [:create_new_users]


def authenticate_user_access
  current_user.is_admin 
  #is_admin the attribute in the user model to check for admin.set it false by default
end
```

You can add multiple methods in the :only which requires admin access.